# define a numpy signature for output array of unknown length (for use in numba.guvectorize)

Tags: python, numpy, signature, numba, numpy-ufunc

Is it possible to create a signature for a `numpy` `ufunc` that returns an 1d array of unknown length?

I have a function that takes in one array `x` of length `(n)` and an array of labels `y` of length `(m)`, performs a reduction and returns the array `out` of unknown size.

The function itself will be wrapped with `numba.guvectorize`:

```py
@guvectorize([(int16[:], float64[:], int32[:], int16[:])], "(n),(m) -> (l)", nopython=True)
def fun(x, y, out):
    #perform stuff
    # ...
    # no return in guvectorize
```

This returns the following error:

> NameError: undefined output symbols: l

My solution would be to pass in a template array of length `l`, but it wouldn't be used for any calculation, so I'd like to avoid it.

Any ways around this, or is passing in a template the best (and maybe not so bad) solution?

#### Edit:

Some valid points made in the comments I want to address:

The function is supposed to be applied on an array with dimensions `(x, y, z)` along the `z` dimension, which has length `n`.

The intended purpose of the function is to take each 1d array along `z`

`[z,z,z,z,z,z,z,z,...,z]`

and expand it to length `m`

`[z1,z1,z1,z2,z2,z2,z2,z3,...,zz]`

and finally the corresponding values are averaged

`[z1,z2,z3,z4,z5,z6,z7,z8,...,zz]`

resulting in an array with length `l`.

I know beforehand exactly what the sizes `m`, `n` and `l` will be - I just need to "tell" it to the function. This is why I also don't expect any jagged outputs.

The fastest way to apply this to a big 3d array using `xarray` is with `guvectorize`. But this results in the issue above.

A working solution is to pass in a template of length `l`.

For comparison, I've created a `@njit` wrapped function, that manually loops over the first two dimension, applying the same functionality.

Unfortunately this is still about 4 times slower than using `guvectorize`., so I'd like to use `guvectorize` for this application.

Comment: That doesn't make sense as a ufunc - there's no way to broadcast this, since the shapes don't work out right.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `numba.jit`, not `numba.guvectorize`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I'm explicitly using `guvectorize` because the function needs to be applied to a dimension of a 3d array (with the help of `xarray` and `dask`) - so as far as I can see it, no way to use `jit` for that

Comment: How do you plan to avoid jagged output?

Comment: Well, I exactly know the input dimensions and the desired output dimensions, as well as the reductions happening. So I don't expect jagged output (edit: which is why I didn't give it too much thought)